# Teradata bteq sql to remove duplicate record with min(column) in table

Tags: database, teradata

I have a table in Teradata. It has 5 columns A,B,C,D,E . C is the unique column and it is numeric . I need to clean up this table by deleting duplicate records which has minimum value in C column. Example shown below

Example

```
A   B   C   D   E
100 ABC 1   23  24
200 XYZ 4   31  45
100 ABC 3   23  24
300 LMN 6   25  26
200 XYZ 7   31  45
```

Expected output

```
A   B   C   D   E
100 ABC 3   23  24
200 XYZ 7   31  45
300 LMN 6   25  26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the QUALIFY statement which allows you to filter the result set of a query using a Window Function:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY C DESC) = 1;
```

The Window Function here is putting a row_number (1 through N) on each group of distinct `A` fields starting with the highest C `ORDER BY C DESC` then choosing only the record that got a `1`.

---

For other RDBMS's (as well as Teradata) you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE c = (SELECT max(c) FROM yourtable WHERE t1.a = a);
```

Comment: Your query will just display the unique rows which has max(c) . I would like to delete the duplicate rows which has min(c) . Any idea please ?

Comment: I got the solution - DELETE zt FROM table zt
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table ex
    WHERE ex.A = zt.A
    AND ex.C > zt.C
);  Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is

```
DELETE zt FROM table zt
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table ex
    WHERE ex.A = zt.A
    AND ex.C > zt.C
);
```